# Hooking Python code using Detours

Tags: python, windows, dll, code-injection, detours

I built a simple Python gui application("App.py") that I am trying to hook using detours. My understanding is that Python should use Windows dll's at some point and I am trying to hook these function calls.

For that purpose I am using detours withdll.exe :

```
withdll.exe /d:"myDLL.dll" "myprogram.exe"
```

Because withdll.exe doesn't accept running a program with arguments ("python.exe App.py"), I tried creating a bat file starter.bat as follows:

```
cd appdir
python App.py
```

And then running:

```
withdll.exe /d:"myDLL.dll" "starter.bat"
```

However this approach only hooks the background cmd process.

Is there a workaround to make detours hook the Python.exe process of my script ?

Comment: Withdll source code is available, its license allows it, so why not add the required feature youself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through detours withdll.exe source code and found out that it can take command line arguments, the issue was solved using:

```
withdll.exe /d:"myDLL.dll" "pathtopython/Python.exe" "pathtoscript/myscript.py"
```